# Angular - active class isn't removing on next button click

Tags: angular, dom-events, angular-directive

I don't know how to solve this issue, but any help would be great. 
The problem is, in this quiz app when I mark a true/false it gets an active class but when I go to next question the active class is still there though question is changed. How to change the condition for the next questions

```
<div class="statement-row"
             *ngFor="let item of search.options;let j = index">
          <div class="statement-question">
            <div class="qitem-text">
              <div class="qitem-textbox">
                <p>{{item.statement}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ccq">
              <div class="qitem qclose"
                   [ngClass]="{'qclose-active': selectAnswer[j]?.dirty && (selectAnswer[j].select == 'true')}"
                   (click)="selectAnswer[j] = {select: 'true', dirty: 'true'};">
                <i class="qitembox qclose-icon"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="qitem qtick"
                   [ngClass]="{'qtick-active': selectAnswer[j]?.dirty && (selectAnswer[j].select == 'false')}"
                   (click)="selectAnswer[j] = {select: 'false', dirty: 'true'};">
                <i class="qitembox qtick-icon"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="questions-actions text-right">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="previou(search.index)">
        Back
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="next(search.index)">
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is an option..

Make `select` and `dirty` boolean values instead of strings (e.g `false` instead of `'false'`).

Change `&& (selectAnswer[j].select == 'true')` to `&& selectAnswer[j].select`

Change `&& (selectAnswer[j].select == 'false')` to `&& !selectAnswer[j].select`

Then add a function which you call from your `next()` and `previous()` functions.

```
private resetSelectedAnswers() {
    this.selectedAnswers.forEach(answer => {
      answer.dirty = false;
      answer.select = false;
    });
  }
```